# Getting maximum sequential streak with events

Tags: postgresql

I’m having trouble getting my head around this.

I’m looking for a single query, if possible, running PostgreSQL 9.6.6 under pgAdmin3 v1.22.1

I have a table with a date and a row for each event on the date:

```
Date        Events
2018-12-10  1
2018-12-10  1
2018-12-10  0
2018-12-09  1
2018-12-08  0
2018-12-07  1
2018-12-06  1
2018-12-06  1
2018-12-06  1
2018-12-05  1
2018-12-04  1
2018-12-03  0
```

I’m looking for the longest sequence of dates without a break. In this case, `2018-12-08` and `2018-12-03` are the only dates with no events, there are two dates with events between `2018-12-08` and `today`, and four between `2018-12-8` and `2018-12-07` - so I would like the answer of 4.

I know I can group them together with something like:

```
Select Date, count(Date) from Table group by Date order by Date Desc
```

To get just the most recent sequence, I’ve got something like this- the `subquery` returns the most recent date with no events, and the outer query counts the dates after that date:

```
select count(distinct date) from Table
where date>
  ( select date from Table
    group by date
    having count (case when Events is not null then 1 else null end) = 0
    order by date desc
    fetch first row only)
```

But now I need the longest streak, not just the most recent streak.

Thank you!

Comment: In the sample data it seems like every date is represented in the table. Is that the case with the actual data?

Comment: Good question. Every date should be represented, but there is a very small chance it won't. There may or may not be data for today- and of course, there's a finite start point, which may be fairly recent.

Comment: @GeorgeS Your answer, based on my information was great, thank you. However, I've discovered that there may well be gaps in the dates. A streak should ignore gaps and only count the rows with events between the two dates. I'm trying to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instinct is a good one in looking at the rows with zero events and working off them. We can use a subquery with a window function to get the "gaps" between zero event days, and then in a query outside it take the record we want, like so:

```
select * 
from (
  select date as day_after_streak
   , lag(date) over(order by date asc) as previous_zero_date 
   , date - lag(date) over(order by date asc) as difference
   , date_part('days', date - lag(date) over(order by date asc) ) - 1 as streak_in_days
  from dates

  group by date
  having sum(events) = 0 ) t 
where t.streak_in_days is not null
order by t.streak_in_days desc
limit 1
```