# Getting maximum sequential streak with events - updated question

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've previously posted a similar question to this, but an update on the parameters has meant that the solution posted wouldn't work, and I've had trouble trying to work out how to integrate the revised requirement. I'm not sure the protocol in here- it appears that I can't post an updated question to the original post at [Getting maximum sequential streak with events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735749/getting-maximum-sequential-streak-with-events?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I’m looking for a single query, if possible, running PostgreSQL 9.6.6 under pgAdmin3 v1.22.1

I have a table with a date and a row for each event on the date:

```
    Date        Events
    2018-12-10  1
    2018-12-10  1
    2018-12-10  0
    2018-12-09  1
    2018-12-08  0
    2018-12-08  0
    2018-12-07  1
    2018-12-06  1
    2018-12-06  1
    2018-12-06  0
    2018-12-06  1
    2018-12-04  1
    2018-12-03  0
```

I’m looking for the longest sequence of dates without a break. In this case, `2018-12-08` and `2018-12-03` are the only dates with no events, there are two dates with events between `2018-12-08` and `today`, and three between `2018-12-8` and `2018-12-07` - so I would like the answer of 3.

I know I can group them together with something like:

```
Select Date, count(Date) from Table group by Date order by Date Desc
```

To get just the most recent sequence, I’ve got something like this- the `subquery` returns the most recent date with no events, and the outer query counts the dates after that date:

```
select date, count(distinct date) from Table
where date>
  ( select date from Table
    group by date
    having count (case when Events is not null then 1 else null end) = 0
    order by date desc
    fetch first row only)
group by date
```

But now I need the longest streak, not just the most recent streak.

I had assumed when I posted previously that there were rows for every date in the range. But this assumption wasn't correct, so the answer given doesn't work. I also need the query to return the start and end date for the range.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "four between `2018-12-8` and `2018-12-07`"?

Comment: Sorry, that should be three. So that's three separate days. I've edited my post.

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding where you get the figure 3 from, between the 8th December and 7th December

Comment: There were three days with events. 2018-12-06 had three events on the one day, so that counts as one. 

I'm looking for a count of separate dates, not a count of rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign group by doing a cumulative count of the 0s.  Then count the distinct dates in each group:

```
select count(*), min(date), max(date), count(distinct date)
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where events = 0) over (order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp
order by count(distinct date) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon.

However, this doesn't work, because I didn't realise that there were details I wasn't aware of.

For any date, there may be more than one row with zero events. There may be zero events on any date where there are events. 

I need the number of days where an event has occurred, even if there are rows with zero events.

I've edited the example in the question to show.